# Does System.exit(0) as the last statement make a difference?

Tags: java

**Java 1.5+**

How is class A different from class B ?

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Ending..");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Ending..");
    }
}
```

If `System.exit(0)` or `System.exit(1)` is the last statement of the program to be executed, would class A and class B behave the same in all aspects of the program execution ?

I understand that by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class A` "explicitly" shuts down. This means that if there are any *non-daemon* threads still running, they will be stopped explicitly (being told to, instead of dying out).

`Class B` shuts down "implicitly", seeing how the main thread is the only non-daemon thread running in that case, and after the print statement, it'll end.

Check out the documentation for [Thread#setDaemon(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29): *"**The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads**."*

In the end, the application is shutdown, so I guess it doesn't really make a difference, other than the first is being told to shutdown, and the second one "dies out". It would be best to let the thread die out, rather than being told to. It's one less extra step; you also wouldn't need to bother executing any extra statements within the `exit(int)` method. The code for that method can be found here: [GrepCode: Shutdown#exit(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Shutdown.java#Shutdown.exit%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't explicitly specify an exit code with `System.exit()` the default exit code is `0`.
- I'm not sure about that, but it *may* affect `File.deleteOnExit()` calls.
- `Systeme.exit()` terminates your program immediately, even if other non-daemon threads are still running. In case of `ClassB` these threads and your program would continue to run until all non-daemon threads exited.